# How to recursively get the last element of each list contained within a map in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, recursion

I am new to Scala and was wondering how to recursively get the last element from each list contained in a map. The data contained in the map is read in from a text file which contains information about football teams and their points tallies for the past 5 seasons:

```
   Manchester United, 72, 86, 83, 90, 94
   Manchester City, 80, 84, 91, 77, 88
   Chelsea, 76, 85, 92, 87, 84
   Arsenal, 70, 79, 81, 76, 83
   Liverpool, 69, 77, 80, 73, 79
```

The data is stored as Map[String, List[Int]] and I wish to return a map of type Map[String, Int] which will provide me with the most recent points tally for each team, e.g. Manchester United: 94, Manchester City: 88 etc. I am currently managing to achieve this by reversing the lists and getting the head, as shown below. How would I do this recursively?

```
  val teamdata = readTextFile("teams.txt")

  def menuOptionOne(): Boolean = {
    //1 - Show most recent points tally for each team
    menuMostRecent(mostRecentPoints)
    true
  }


  def readTextFile(file: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    var mapBuilder: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map()
    try {
      for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines()) {     
      val linesplit = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList   
      mapBuilder = mapBuilder ++ Map(linesplit.head -> linesplit.tail.map(_.toInt))
      }
    } 
    catch {
      case ex: Exception => println("Exception Thrown")
    }
    mapBuilder
  }


  def menuMostRecent(f: () => Map[String, Int]) = {
    f() foreach {case (x,y) => println(s"$x: $y")}
  }  


  def mostRecentPoints():Map[String, Int] = {
    ListMap(teamdata.mapValues(_.reverse.head).toSeq.sortBy(_._1):_*)
  }
```

Comment: 1 - Why does `menuOptionOne()` return `Boolean`? 2 - `mostRecentPoints()` goes to a lot of trouble get the data elements sorted but it returns a `Map()` which, by definition, has no order. 3 - I don't think recursion is going to buy you anything. Replace `reverse.head` with `last` and you're good to go.

Comment: 1 - A loop is used to control the menu functionality, if an integer is entered, the corresponding menu option is invoked e.g. 1 for 'menuOptionOne()', and the loop for reading input will keep running until the integer which invokes menu option (returns false) for exiting the loop is entered. 

2 - This is the method I found of how to alphabetically sort the map. Is there another or better way to sort the teams in the map alphabetically? 

3 - This works well but being new to Scala, I was wondering how to do this recursively to get a better grasp and understanding of recursion in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this which highlights the recursive approach explicitly is to define a small function to get the last element in the list using recursion as follows:

```
  def recList(l : List[Int]) : Int = l match {
      case Nil => throw new Exception("Empty list")
      case x :: Nil => x
      case x :: xs => recList(xs)
  }
```

This is also making use of Scala's pattern matching facility to deconstruct the list. Then it is simply a case of calling this function on your map:

```
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(MU -> List(10, 20, 30), MC -> List(50, 55, 60))

scala> s.mapValues(recList)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(MU -> 30, MC -> 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val x = Map[String, Seq[Int]]("MU" -> Seq(20,30,56,45),"MC" -> Seq(20,30,56,45,78))

x.map(a => a._1 -> a._2.last)
```

Isn't this simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use List.last? I do not think it is a good idea to make wheel yourself.